# handle error json.loads on scrapy response.xpath

Tags: json, xpath, scrapy, handle

I try to get the data using scrapy from a website using following command:

```
jsondata = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').extract_first()
microdata = json.loads(jsondata)   
author = microdata["author"]["name"]
editor = microdata["editor"]["name"]
daten = microdata["datePublished"]
```

but it give me an error if the json part "//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()" not found on the website.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you add the url so I can check it?

Comment: @SuperUser, this example of url with json https://www.antaranews.com/berita/2320530/gempa-di-padang-lawas-utara-dipicu-oleh-aktivitas-sesar-sumatera and this example of url with no json: https://www.antaranews.com/foto/2320526/penjualan-pernak-pernik-hiasan-kemerdekaan. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scrapy
import json

class RefSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "refspider"

    start_urls = ['https://www.antaranews.com/berita/2320530/gempa-di-padang-lawas-utara-dipicu-oleh-aktivitas-sesar-sumatera',
                  'https://www.antaranews.com/foto/2320526/penjualan-pernak-pernik-hiasan-kemerdekaan']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsondata = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').extract_first()

        if jsondata is not None:
            microdata = json.loads(jsondata)
            author = microdata["author"]["name"]
            editor = microdata["editor"]["name"]
            daten = microdata["datePublished"]
```